# Japanese letters aren't showing correctly with UTF8

Tags: language, unicode, utf-8, japanese

So I have these several files in Japanese text, that was meant for Japanese computers to use. I first unzipped them, to find a completely garbled unreadable text for the title of files. I went to language preference and changed my non-unicode language to Japanese, with UTF-8.

After that, the texts improved - Kanjis were displayed correctly, but Hiraganas and Katakanas were bugged out in a different way, in black diamonds. Like this:�閧�̂��܂��i���b�j

Do I have to change my language to UTF-16? if so, How will I do it? It's ruined a game experience for me once from this bug, I need to fix it because its ruining my game experience again on a different game.

Comment: You should post an example of such a file.

Comment: What OS? Did you install the correct language packs? [Win7 used to include a lot more by default, Win10 needs you to add manually] CJK is commonly missing in WIn10, though for full support you'd probably need the dedicated Japanese pack.

Comment: What program is displaying this text – is it a game or is it Notepad or some other text editor? Are you sure the file is in UTF-8 and not e.g. SJIS?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured i out, I disabled the UTF8 in the advanced language settings and restarted the system, and everything worked out fine. I use Win10 btw